# UTF-8 string delimiter

Tags: utf-8

I am parsing a binary protocol which has UTF-8 strings interspersed among raw bytes. This particular protocol prefaces each UTF-8 string with a short (two bytes) indicating the length of the following UTF-8 string. This gives a maximum string length 2^16 > 65 000 which is more than adequate for the particular application.

My question is, is this a standard way of delimiting UTF-8 strings?

Comment: if you have the length already, why do you need a delimiter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't call that delimiting, more like "length prefixing". Some people call them [Pascal strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_%28computer_science%29#Representations) since in the early days the language Pascal was one of the popular ones that stored strings that way in memory.

I don't think there's a formal standard specifically for just that, as it's a rather obvious way of storing UTF-8 strings (or any strings of bytes for that matter). It's defined over and over as a part of many standards that deal with messages that contain strings, though.

Comment: Yes, I was being too loose in my usage of the term 'delimiter' -- I was interchanging it with the term 'length prefix' since they serve an equivalent function in this case, but delimiter really does refer only to a terminating character. 'Defined over and over' is what I wanted to hear :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

UTF8 is not normally de-limited, you should be able to spot the multibyte characters in there by using the rules mentioned here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description

Answer (score 0):

i would use a delimiter which starts with 0x11......
but if you send raw bytes you will have to exclude this delimiter from the data\messages processed ,this means that if there is a user input similar to that delimiter, you will have to convert it.

if the user inputs any utf8 represented char you may simply send it as is.