# Least used unicode delimiter

Tags: php, parsing, unicode, nlp, unicode-string

I'm trying to tag my text with a delimiter at specific places that will be used later for parsing. I want to use a delimiter character that is least frequently used. I'm currently looking at the "\2" or the U+0002 character. Is that safe enough to use? What other suggestions are there? The text is unicode and will have both english and non-english characters.

A want to use a character that can still be "exploded()" by PHP.

**Edit:**

Also I want to be able to display this piece of text on screen (to the browser) and the delimiter will be "invisible" to the user. I can definitely use a str_replace() to get rid of visible delimiters, but if there are good invisible delimiters, then no such processing is needed.

Comment: use more than one character :)

Comment: maybe you'll make a delimiter string (something like [!--!]) that is not very frequently used? =)

Comment: You could encode text like that: `[lenght]-text[length]-text2[length]-text3...` (for instance `3-foo6-foobar`, expanding to `['foo', 'foobar']`), which would be a surefire way to avoid the conflicts that `explode` can bring while remaining manageably easy to parse.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5847982/469210 is a similar question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this is only for an internal representation (i.e. *not* for interchange and storage), then you can use a non-character code point such as U+FFFF. [Java uses that as the signal that a CharacterIterator is done, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482683/can-a-valid-unicode-string-contain-ffff-is-java-characteriterator-broken/3482698#3482698).

Comment: This will be stored in MySQL as a TEXT field. If I get that field content in my PHP app, will that code point still show up?

Comment: You should ask that the MySQL docs. If in doubt, use a BLOB instead. Or normalize your database a little more instead of doing parsing in PHP.

Comment: @samxli, if you store it in a MySQL table, you could also make a separate table to store the data. What you're doing smells like improvements over your database design is possible.

Comment: The text is an article segment. And I need to tag that segment text with the delimiter for another layer of processing later on. But that text will still be shown to the user.